# WLJSX.Ajax on stock browser (blackberry 5)

Tags: ajax, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

**$.ajax** calls do not work in blackberry 5.x.

Do you know if the stock browser of a blackberry 5.x will be able to run a **WL.Client.invokeProcedure** request?

Answer (score 0):

While `WL.Client.invokeProcedure` *should* work on BlackBerry OS 5.0, please note that BlackBerry OS 5.0 is **not supported** anymore in Worklight. Only BlackBerry OS 6, 7 and 10 are supported.